# How to custom css z-index (more 1000) of ngx-material-timepicker on a Material Dialog (MatDialog)?

Tags: angular, angular-material

My `ngx-timepicker-field` is in `MatDialog`. When my timepicker is display, he's behind the `MatDialog` modal popup.

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PopupComponent, {
    data: {
        ...
    },
    position: {
        top: '50px'
    }
});
```

**PopupComponent:**

```
@ViewChild('sendAlertHour', {static: false} ) sendAlertHour:  NgxTimepickerFieldComponent;

<div>
    <ngx-timepicker-field #sendAlertHour></ngx-timepicker-field>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found **a workaround**. I change `z-index` of `MatDialog`

I add this in global CSS file in my Angular app:

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
    z-index: 500 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In the global stylesheet (styles.scss) add the following:

```
.timepicker-overlay {
  z-index: 1100 !important;
}

.timepicker-backdrop-overlay {
  z-index: 1100 !important;
}
```

This will show timepicker above the material dialog. Solution found [here](https://github.com/Agranom/ngx-material-timepicker/issues/244#issuecomment-545045906).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem editing the global angular scss (styles.scss):

```css
.timepicker-overlay {
    z-index: 10000000 !important;
}

.timepicker-backdrop-overlay {
    z-index: 10000000 !important;
}
```